# Unable to resolve service for type with dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, redis

I am getting this DI error, although I have read other posts with the same error, it wasn't enough to find what is causing this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'WatsonConnection.Interfaces.ICacheManagement' while attempting to activate 'WatsonConnection.Controllers.CacheManagementController'.

The configure services at the startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{            
    services.AddSingleton<ICacheManagement, CacheManagementService>();
    services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(
         ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(Configuration["Redis:ConnectionString"])
        );

    services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
    {
        options.Configuration = Configuration["Redis:ConnectionString"];
        
    });
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddControllers();
   
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WatsonConnector", Version = "v1" });
        
    });
}
```

This is my controller which I'm trying to implement the service:

```
public class CacheManagementController : ControllerBase
{
    ICacheManagement cacheManagement;   


    public CacheManagementController(ICacheManagement _cacheMgmt)
    {
        this.cacheManagement = _cacheMgmt;
    }

    [HttpGet("CachedKeys")]
    public IActionResult GetListCacheKeys([FromQuery][DefaultValue("*")] string pattern)
    {                       
        return Ok(cacheManagement.GetListCacheKeys(pattern));
    }
}
```

The service implementation:

```
public class CacheManagementService : ICacheManagement
{
    private  IConnectionMultiplexer multiplexer;
    private ICacheManagement cache;
    public CacheManagementService(IConnectionMultiplexer multiplexer)
    {           
        this.multiplexer = multiplexer;
    }
    public IEnumerable<RedisKey> GetListCacheKeys([DefaultValue("*"), FromQuery] string pattern)
    {
       
        var keys = multiplexer
         .GetServer(multiplexer
             .GetEndPoints()
             .First())
         .Keys(pattern: pattern ?? "*").ToArray();
        return keys;
    }
}
```

And this is the Interface:

```
public interface ICacheManagement
{
    IEnumerable<RedisKey> GetListCacheKeys([FromQuery][DefaultValue("*")] string pattern);
}
```

As I see, I have specified within the configure services the singleton to explicity pair the service to the interface, but that doesn't seen enough, any ideas?

Comment: Can you share how you registered your singleton pair in the configure services?

Comment: @AnthonySerranoBianco  services.AddSingleton<ICacheManagement, CacheManagementService>();
I have pasted the configure services within the question

Comment: @GabrielManzini check your entire object graph and make sure all the necessary dependencies are registered with the container so that they can be resolved.

Comment: Based on the currently shown code, the issue may be with the `IConnectionMultiplexer` implementation.

Comment: This API is within the same solution as another API, starting this one alone solves the problem

Comment: Can you comment all the code in the `GetListCacheKeys` and add some hard-code data to make sure the service itself is ok and then let's troubleshot the case. Per my view, I can't find any issue on the configuration, so I think it's time for a further debug.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that might happen because you have same interface in the inner private field of CacheManagementService called “cache”.